# How to enumerate all Unicode canonically equivalent sequences in Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode

Does there exist a standard Perl module or function that, given a Unicode [Combining Character Sequence](http://unicode.org/glossary/#combining_character_sequence) (or, more generally, an arbitrary Unicode text string), will generate a list of all canonically equivalent strings?

For example, if given the character U+1EAD, I'd like to get back a list of all these canonically equivalent sequences:

```
0061 0302 0323
0061 0323 0302
00E2 0323
1EA1 0302
1EAD
```

(I don't particularly care whether the interface is in terms of arrays of USVs or utf strings.)

Comment: [Unicode::Normalize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode::Normalize) does the opposite. I don't know of anything that does what you want.

Comment: fwiw, the curious might wonder why I want to do this, and there are several uses:  One is in building test data for other code; another is for building OpenType logic inside fonts so they can display all the canonically equivalent sequences correctly.

Comment: I thought it might be possible to use brute force the solution (by using NFC on substrings of permutations of the NFD form of the input), but it can't be done that way. `0915 093C` is canonically equivalent to `0958`, but there's no way to get from `0915 093C` to `0958` using NFC.

Comment: I think the input needs to be an *Extended Grapheme Cluster* rather than a *Combining Character Sequence* to handle the decomposition of HANGUL SYLLABLE GA.

Answer (score 2):

Is this an XY problem? If you want to compare/match 2 unicode strings and you're worried that different ways of encoding the accented characters would create false negatives, then the best way to do this would be to normalize the 2 strings using one of the normalization functions from Unicode::Normalize, before doing the comparison or match.

Otherwise it gets a little messy.

You *could* get the complete character name using `charnames::viacode(0x1EAD);` (for U+1EAD it would be *LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX AND DOT BELOW*), and get the various composing characters by splitting the name on WITH|AND. Then you could generate all combinations (checking that they exist!) of the base character + modifiers and the other modifiers. At this point you will run into the problem of matching the combining characters names in the full name (eg *CIRCUMFLEX*) with the combining character real name (*COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT*). There are probably rules for this, but I don't know them.

This would be my naive attempt, there may be better ways of doing this, but since so far no one has volunteered the information...

Comment: As far as I understand, the OP asks for some method which, when fed with "'A' plus 'ring'" would return all the possible characters which normalize to 'A'+'ring', including the singleton-Angstroem character, which itself would never be the result of a normalization. Interesting.

Comment: For my purposes, whether or not singleton decompositions are included should be optional, but yes, Kerrek, you have the basic idea. I have an algorithm which will give me what I need -- I just wondered whether there was already a standard way to do this -- if not I'll work toward publishing a module on CPAN.

Comment: Decomposing a grapheme into its various composing characters can be done using aforementioned Unicode::Normalize's NFD. No need to parse the charname, which I won't work in all cases (e.g. HANGUL SYLLABLE GA).